# NSTimer strange problem

Tags: iphone

I have 2 ViewController(RootViewController is UITabBarController, ViewController1 links to the item of UITabBarController)

in RootViewController

```
-(void)startTimer:(NSInteger)v;
{
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(timerFired:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES]; 


}


- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer {


    [vViewController1 doSomething];
}
```

in ViewController1

```
-(void)doSomething;
{
   //I set breakpoint but never be fired
}
```

timerFired is activated but the function doSomething in ViewController1 never been fired.

Welcome any comment

Thanks

interdev

Comment: Are you sure `vViewController1` is non-nil?

Comment: Could you show how you are getting a handle to vViewController1? Also, the property definition if you are using one.

Comment: I bet you anything that `vViewController1` is nil.

Comment: ViewController1 links to UITabBarController item, I select the item that links to ViewController1, so it has been activated

Comment: Have you tried something like `NSLog(@"vViewController1 = %@", vViewController1);` just before the line `[vViewController1 doSomething];` just to make sure?

Comment: I'm gonna go with @Tom Dalling and say your vViewController1 is nil

Comment: sorry, I made mistake :-(, vViewController1 is nil, before I always construct my self's multi-viewcotrolller , this is my first time to use UITabBarController, so James Huddleston  and Tom Dalling and Jason Coco are right, but how can I choose your reply as correct answer?

Comment: No worries. I'm glad you got it solved.

Comment: Glad to help. Don't worry about the points. Daniel T.'s answer is correct too, so he can have them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know for a fact that timerFired: is being called, then the only reason that doSomething won't get called is if vViewController1 is nill. Check that again.

Answer (score 2):

The `self` in `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` `target:self` means RootViewController, so it will only invoke `doSomething` in RootViewController but not in ViewController1.

Comment: Thanks. But I really need to call the function doSomething in ViewController1, how can I do?

Comment: It invokes `timerFired:` on `RootViewController`, which in turn calls `doSomething` on (what is supposedly) a `ViewController1` object.